# Concern on the MQ data backup during migration

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i'm working on qmgr migration from 6.0 to 7.0, but i got problem when restoring V6.0 queue manager from 7.0 on `windows`. After re-installing MQ 6.0, i copied back the previous backup QMGR data and log, and then tried to start up that QMGR, for instance TEST01. However, that command `strmqm TEST01` returns with no such QMGR existed.

The restore procedure i refer to is from infor center below

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp

and i backup and restore MQGR data and log through as below:

**Backup**

`copy C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Qmgrs\TEST01 under another path
copy C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\log\TEST01 under another path`

**Restore**
`copy above backup folder back to target path`

So according to above operation, did i miss anything or do something wrong?

**UPDATE:**
This issue has been fixed. I forgot backing up the configuration information from the registry and restored it then. That's why MQ cannot recognize my QMGR at the very beginning.

Additionally, I've got another question here:
how to transfer configuration information from the registry to the mqs.ini file?

Comment: sorry for my fault with misunderstanding the rule to answer my own question, and thanks for your update @T.Rob

Comment: Typically, answering your own question is OK. But in this case your answer included a follow-up question and it is impossible to vote on or accept answers when the question itself is posted as an answer. In those cases it is customary to update the original post or post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been fixed. i forgot backing up the configuration information from the registry and restored it then. that's why MQ cannot recognize my QMGR at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You are far better off not to migrate QMgrs but rather to create new ones at the new version.  Although IBM has always provided an upgrade path, the implementation of certain functionality differs from version to version.  For example, on Windows the registry settings in V6 are no longer used in V7.1 and higher.  The requirement to upgrade usually comes from the belief that replacing the QMgr somehow loses something.

In fact, this is rarely the case. There is also nothing special about a QMgr that well-designed client applications would need to know its name.  The host, port and channel uniquely identify a QMgr for a client application.  If the app specifies the QMgr's name and it does not match, the connection fails. But the app can specify a blank QMgr name and the connection will succeed.  The QMgr's name is automatically filled into the Reply-To QMgr field so requests are properly handled. The only thing that needs to know the name is a QRemote (which can be repointed) or a local app using bindings mode connection.

That said, to answer your question just performing the upgrade to V7.1 or V7.5 will move the QMgr's settings to the ini file.